# Python evaluate math expression with Literal String Interpolation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Today stumbled upon Literal String Interpolation,

```
a=4
b=5
f'{a+b}'
```

the above code gives the output 9,
I was trying to put the operation in variable too.

```
a=4
b='+'
c=5
```

Now how can Literal String Interpolation generate the expected output, saw the [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#how-to-denote-f-strings) but could not make much out of it.

Comment: Hi, 
many thanks for the downvote, kindly let me know what was it downvoted for or it was just for testing whether down vote works or not :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
r = eval(f'{a}{b}{c}')
```

**However**, use of `eval()` is usually not recommended, since it will evaluate any string you feed to it. That includes arbitrary code a malicious user might have put in there somehow.

Comment: You don't need the `+`, `eval(f"{a}{b}{c}")` will work.

Comment: @stybl, yup did see another post on stackoverflow that eval is evil, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string